# Debian package creation error with virtualenv

Tags: deb

I am creating a deb file and I need to have dh_virtualenv, but it doesn't work:

```
morissizo$lambo:/dev/kisya/$ dh_virtualenv --version
dh_virtualenv 0.10
```

Here's my Build-Depends in control file:

```
Build-Depends: python3, dh_virtualenv (>= 0.10)
```

When I try `make` I get:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package kisya
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.8
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by morissizo <morissizo@lambo>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build kisya
dpkg-source: warning: can't parse dependency dh_virtualenv
dpkg-source: error: error occurred while parsing Build-Depends
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source --before-build kisya gave error exit status 255
make: *** [deb] Error 2
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be caused by :

1) Since 0.1 version is NOT in the default source, you might have installed it in a different location that is not (by default) recongnized by your ENV Variables. (location which is not included in your $PATH)

2) and/or you don't have it in your control file.

**Solution:**

1) Make sure you have this in your control file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
      dh $@ --with python-virtualenv
```

2) Remove it from your `Build-Depends`. It will be automatically included from your control file.